# Set width of ng-content element to the size of children passed through

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a view that looks like this:

```
<base-carousel>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" carouselItem>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</base-carousel>
```

Where the template for `base-carousel` looks like this:

```
<div [style.width]="getTrackWidth()">
  <ng-content select="[carouselItem]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

and the class for `base-carousel` looks *kind of* like this:

```
@ContentChildren(CarouselItem, {read: ElementRef}) items: ElementRef[];

getTrackWidth(): string {
  return this.items.reduce((accum, curr) =>
      accum + curr.nativeElement.clientWidth, 0) + 'px';
}
```

The problem is that this throws the error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

I then tried changing the `[style.width]` to point to a simple variable with my class looking more like this:

```
trackWidth = '100%';

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.setTrackWidth();
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}

setTrackWidth(): string {
  this.trackWidth = this.items.reduce((accum, curr) =>
      accum + curr.nativeElement.clientWidth, 0) + 'px';
}
```

That fixes the error however now the width is always set to zero and its not picking up the childrens rendered size.

Answer (score 0):

I found using `ngAfterContentInit` was the right lifecycle hook to use and solved my problem.